# How do I echo mySQL rows separately?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, echo

I'm pulling rows from a table in the database:
title and COUNT(id) AS 'count'.

There are two things that I want to accomplish. The first is being accomplished by echoing $row['title'] and $row['count'] in the same line in a WHILE loop.

The second requires some other method. I'm putting it in javascript right on the page. When I do by echoing title and count (as above), It only returns the first record. **Is there a way to echo each record separately, so that each time I echo, it will get the next record?**

Comment: @Rocket // Create the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Title');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Views');
      data.addRows([
        ['" . $title . "'," . $count . "],
      ]);

Comment: @nitsuj: You should have edited your orginal post and added code there.

Comment: @Rocket You can see the code in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014116/mysql-get-field-and-count-occurances-chart-with-google-charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);` to return the mysql resource back to the beginning of the list. Then for your Javascript, use another `while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` loop.

Comment: So...

(first while statement) {

}

mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

(second while statement) {

   (javascript with echoes in it)

}

??

Comment: I'll post the answer ... it was a combination of mysql_data_seek and moving the second while statement to be INSIDE of the javascript. Thanks!!!